# Can I plan to make a Siyum in the nine days to eat meat?

Tags: halacha, meat, nine-days, siyum

The Rema says that one can eat meat in a Seudas Mitzva during the nine days. Does that mean I can purposely plan to make a Siyum then? Can I invite whoever I want? If not, what are the parameters?

Comment: As the Aruch Haschan states, why would anyone _want_ to have a siyum during the 9 days when you can't celebrate properly?! (Ah, the perspective of the gedolim...)

Answer (score 5):

These questions are dealt with [here:](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2014/07/siyum-during-nine-days.html)

> The Shulchan Aruch (OC 551:9) writes that one mustn’t eat meat or drink wine during the nine days. The Rema (OC 551:10) adds that if one has a seudas mitzva during this time then one may partake of wine and meat as such celebrations are incomplete without them. This includes Shabbos meals, a bris seuda, a pidyon haben, or a siyum.
>
> The Aruch Hashulchan (551:28) strongly disapproved of postponing one’s siyum to coincide with the nine days in order to eat meat, though writes that if one was learning something (extra) and planning on making the siyum then, that is commendable (See Mishna Berura 551:28). The Lubavitcher Rebbe encouraged people to specifically make a siyum during this time, saying it would add light to this dark period (though his minhag was not to eat meat then). Other poskim write that one should avoid making a siyum afer the 6th of Av (See Moadei Yeshurun p132).
>
> The Mishna Berura (551:75) writes that anyone who would normally be invited to one’s siyum may participate and eat meat, too, though one shouldn’t invite extra people.
> While some poskim hold that only one who was present for the learning and siyum may partake of the meal, the consensus of poskim (Minchas Yitzchak 9:45; Rivevos Ephraim 3:343; Teshuvos Vehanhagos 1:300) is that one who came late mat still join in and eat meat (See Mishna Berura 470:10).

Comment: Chayei Adam also strongly condemns people who *go* to siyumim in order to eat meat and drink wine. IIRC his actual words are שיכורים אלו שבאים רק לשתות.

Comment: From what I learned, one may not speed up or slow down learning so that the learning finishes during the nine days.

Comment: @Danno, if you have a source for that (i.e. if you indicate from whom/where you learned it), I suggest you post it as an answer.

Comment: @Danno I believe you're simply reiterating what the Aruch Hashulchan writes (see beginning of 2nd paragraph above), though he doesn't say it in quite so many words.

Comment: @msh210 "If one would not otherwise have finished the Masechta he was learning in time for a Siyum in the 'nine days' he should not increase or decrease his speed of learning in order to have it "conveniently" fall out in time for a meat meal in the 'nine days'.(Mishna Berura Siman 551 S"K 73)" http://halachafortodaycom.blogspot.com/p/week-in-review.html

Comment: @Danno "as an answer"

Comment: @msh210 I don't see it as a useful answer on its own, simply a supplement to what is a fine answer already.