# Finish it later and make a siyum?

Tags: halacha, torah-study, time, hefsek-interruption, siyum

Suppose someone part of a work of Torah and, later, picks up where he left off. Can he make a *siyum* (e.g. to exempt *b'choros* from fasting *erev Pesach* or to allow wine before 9 *Av*)?

---

Possibly this depends on circumstances, in which case please detail the different cases in your answer. Some things that I suspect might possible matter are the length of the interruption, the intent of the original study (to learn the whole thing or just a bit), and the amount studied (an entire chapter or the like versus a fractional piece).

Comment: I think we have a q related to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/43894/759 which discusses pushing off a siyum to more useful times. it could be related or a dupe of this.

Comment: @DoubleAA certainly related, but that's asking about the permissibility of planning it for the nine days [not necessary with breeak] whereas this is asking about whether it's an official _siyum_ if one took a break. Two very different questions AFAICT.

Comment: I'm not sure why it would be a problem.

Comment: @Ypmypn Nor I, but it seems funny to make a _siyum_ on, say, _Bava M'tzia_ (_Bavli_) because I learned _Elu M'tzios_ at age ten and the other chapters at age fifty.

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/48951/759 is that a dupe of this?

Answer (score 1):

The only sources I found on this come courtesy of [chaburas.org](http://www.chaburas.org/siyum.html) and say one can wait a bit but not a lot.

> Maharam Mintz claims that when one reaches the end of a tractate, he
>   should delay learning the end until an appropriate time comes for
>   making a siyum. Minchat Yitzchak (2:93) qualifies this by
>   distinguishing between waiting a little and waiting a lot. **One who
>   finishes a tractate the week before Pesach may draw out his learning a
>   bit so as to make a siyum on Erev Pesach, but one who finishes in
>   December should not save the last page for the four months until he
>   needs it to avoid having to fast.** He says that in such a case, one's
>   siyum would not be made out of simcha, but rather out of a desire to
>   satisfy one's physical needs.

Regarding a siyum during the nine days specifically see [here](http://www.congkins.org/nine-days-in-halacha.html)

> However, those who complete a significant portion of learning (e.g. a
>   tractate of Talmud) during the nine days solely for the purpose to eat
>   meat are not universally praised. In fact, the Aruch HaShulchan, while
>   allowing such behavior (suggesting that at least in this way, people
>   will learn Torah) does limit the people participating in this meal to
>   just Torah scholars associated with this learning project [Aruch
>   HaShulchan Orech Chaim 551:28].
>
> Nevertheless, the Mishna Berura, among
>   others does allow broader participation in the meal, extending it to
>   all those who would normally be invited to such a celebration [Mishna
>   Berura 551:75].   Once the week of Tisha B'Av begins (from the Sunday
>   before Tisha B'Av), the number of participants at such a siyum should
>   be limited to a minyan aside from the relatives of the person making
>   the siyum and those who are helping with them meal [Orach Chaim
>   551:10; Mishna Berura, ibid. note 77].

Comment: Your first quote seems to frown on delaying to a specific time rather than on delaying for a long time.